# How can I make mumps when I make bonmin

Tags: coin-or

The tested platform is windows using cygwin. I download bonmin-1.8.8 from https://www.coin-or.org/download/source/Bonmin/.

First, I obtained the third party code with the commands

```
./get.asl 

./get.blas

./get.lapack

./get.mumps
```

then ran the command

```
./configure -C
```

and it shows that the configuration of bonmin is successful.

But then, when I run

```
make
```

There's something wrong with the makefile of Mumps.
It shows a rank mismatch between the actual arguments at (1) and (2)

```
MUMPS/src/dmumps_comm_buffer.F:2670:23:
```

I want to know how can I successfully `make` it?

Comment: Please show text as text not images. We need enough infoprmation so that we can curt and paste your code and then just run it to reproduce what the errors are and then fix it on out machines

Comment: OK.The tested platform is windows using cygwin. I download the bonmin-1.8.8 on the  [link](https://www.coin-or.org/download/source/Bonmin/). First, I obtained the 3rd code with the cmd  './get.asl ' './get.blas'  './get.lapack' and './get.mumps'. After that with the cmd  './configure -c', it shows I configure successfully, but when I wrote 'make', it shows the error that rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and  (2). MUMPS/src/dmumps_comm_buffer.F:2670:23:

Comment: @TommyMa Did you manage to get this working? I'm having the same issues

Comment: I solved this problem by using debian rather than cygwin.